# Tomcat project folder what to do?

Tags: java, tomcat

This question might sound stupid, but I am in trouble.
A developer gave me a ready made application as is. I downloaded the zip file and found that it was not ready to use.

So in the root folder I have te following:

- .settings Folder
- src Folder
- target Folder
- pom.xml File
- .classpath File
- .gitignore File
- .project File
- log.roo File
- .springBeans File

I tried to deploy this folder in Tomcat Manager but nothing happend. Can you give an advice what to do, to get this working?

Comment: You should ask your developer to provide the work in a form and with instructions to be deployed.

Comment: If it is not a secret or confidential code, can you post your code on dropbox ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a maven project that was based on a roo project.

Maven:  http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html

Roo: http://projects.spring.io/spring-roo/

To be able to run this in Tomcat you must first create a war file.

Try this in the folder in which you did this ls:

mvn package

(more details on generating a war file through Maven: http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/)

If it doesn't work then it is because you don't have Maven installed. You also need Java installed.

If you don't know how to get Maven and Java going, then go back to the developer and ask for a "war" file that you can install on Tomcat.

If you have Maven and Java installed, you can simply type "mvn jetty:run" in the command line and that should start a web server on port 8080, with your application name. Something like

`http://localhost:8080/<yourApplicationName>`